# Firefox SVG shape not printing when it has stroke

Tags: firefox, svg

I am having an issue with SVG shapes that have a stroke and trying to get them to print in firefox.

This is the simplest example:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <rect x="0" y="0" rx="15" ry="15" width="300" height="400" style="stroke:black;stroke-width:5;" fill="black" />
    <circle id="FirstCircle" cx="50" cy="50" r="30" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="white" style="opacity:0.75;"/>
    <circle id="SecondCircle" cx="50" cy="150" r="30" fill="white" style="opacity:0.75;"/>
</svg>
```

When I try and print this the first shape does one of two things:

1. It does not show up at all
2. It shows up off center in its bounding box.

The second shape with no stroke shows up as expected, where expected.

When displaying on the screen it shows as expected where expected. The issue olny arises when I try and print.

I have tried with different scale factors (50% - 100%) and the default shrink to fit.

Here is what I get when I try and print it:

[image: imageoutput]

Is this defined behavior or does anyone know how to correct for this?

I am not in love with the stroke on this shape and can easily layer shapes to get the same effect, bt it would be nice to know why this is happeneing.

**EDIT:**

As Robert Longson pointed out this appears to be a Firefox bug. A report was filed [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=894917) and they are looking into it.

Comment: Raise it in [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Core&component=SVG)

Comment: So it is a bug? I was not able to tell if it was something I was doing wrong or if it is something to do with firefox.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the `width` and `height` of the `svg` element to fix this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="300" height="400">
    <rect x="0" y="0" rx="15" ry="15" width="300" height="400" style="stroke:black;stroke-width:5;" fill="black" />
    <circle id="FirstCircle" cx="50" cy="50" r="30" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="white" style="opacity:0.75;"/>
    <circle id="SecondCircle" cx="50" cy="150" r="30" fill="white" style="opacity:0.75;"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: It is displaying on screen just fine, and print preview also works. This appears to be a firefox specific issue. It prints fine in Chrome. I would remove the question since I [filed a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=894917). But if somone else is having the same problem I thought it would be beneficial to be here.